laravel cascadeOnDelete not found
I'm building an API with laravel, and I'm trying to get the migrations to work. However, this migration fails with Method Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::cascadeOnDelete does not exist.
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('stuff', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('image');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->cascadeOnDelete();
    });
}

My app is laravel 10, but this feature is in the docs for laravel 10 and 11. How is it that this method doesn't exist?

The cascadeOnDelete() method is available on the class Illuminate\Database\Schema\ForeignIdColumnDefinition and not on the class Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint, and this is logical because you add the CASCADE constraints on foreign keys.
You probably meant to write something like this:
$table->foreignId("key_id")->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();

Notice that all foreign key constraints are added after the constrained() method.

Thank you. However I would point out in the docs they use identical syntax to what I used: $table->cascadeOnDelete(); -- which seems confusing if the cascade only applies to individual columns.

@user101289 you're absolutely right, it's confusing because in the example they're not clarifying that the cascadeOnDelete() method applies to the result of the constrained() method, and not the $table object.
